# Finding digital root of n digit number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How many steps will be required to find the digital root of a $n$-digit number? E.g., $18$ requires $1$ step but $189$ requires $2$ steps.

Comment: The number of steps is known as "Additive persistence".

Answer (score 1):

Not many.

Let $a(n)$ be the minimum number such that $n$ steps are needed.

So the sequence $a(n)$ begins $0,10,19,199,19999999999999999999999$.

The terms of the sequence are given recursively by
$$
a(n)=2 \cdot 10^{(a(n-1)-1)/9}-1
$$
(see https://oeis.org/A006050).

So, if $0 \le n <10$, then zero steps are needed.

If $10 \le n < 19$, then one step is needed.

If $19 \le n < 199$, then at most two steps are needed.

If $199 \le n <19999999999999999999999$, then at most three steps are needed.

You can continue this process to get a bound for any size $n$.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one step, you only need to compute the remainder under division by 9. But it is more fun to compute digital roots.

Comment: The remainder is always a number between 0 and 8. That is just the definition of the remainder.